# Expanding Video Banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I want to put a `<video>` as a banner on my site, but I don't want it to be fully visible at first. [Here's some concept work of what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibo4f.jpg).

On page load, I'd like it to look like that, with the overlayed play button present.

After a `.click()` event or an `onclick=""` event, I'd like the video to expand, show controls, and play.

Is this at all possible to do with a `<video>` element?

Comment: I had to fix some issues. But see my answer below that should work.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5A66/64/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5A66/64/show

Note: you could also play with the video poster attribute and add your own video still image. You could have than a blurred image and than when the video play you could remove it... Here I moved the video out of the screen a little and animate it when hitting the click.

```
var video = $("#video_32568");
$(".video-container").css({"top":-200});
$(".play-button").click(function() {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
    var video = $("#video_32568").get(0);
    $(".video-container").animate({top:0}, 800, function() {
    video.play();
    });
    return false;
}); 

video.bind("pause ended", function() {
    $(".play-button").css({"backgroundPosition": "center center", "visibility": "visible"});
});

section {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
}
section .play-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/g78bq59h7/button_black_play.png) center 209px no-repeat;
}
section video {
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
 <section>
   <div class="video-container">
    <div class="play-button"></div> 
      <video id="video_32568">
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>  
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose not even having the video there at the beginning. Instead use a placeholder image. On click you replace it with the actual video using JS. This way you can have a nice hand-selected image and also only load the video if requested.

Comment: I ended up using your idea, with bits of Sigma's code! You're both a great help!